# Javascript arguments shifting

Tags: javascript, arguments

Let's assume that we have the following function:

```js
var a = function(data, type){
  var shift = [].shift;
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  console.log(data);
}

a(1,'test', 2, 3);
```

I understand that data and type are just references to specific values in arguments. But why in the end, data is equal to 3?

Comment: The relationship between them are live... the solution is to use a separate array like `var arr = [].slice.call(arguments)` then `shift.call(arr)`

Comment: I know about connection:) I am interested why in the end it is not undefined but 3

Comment: because when you call shift the position of all the values in the formal parameter list changes

Comment: @LeoCaseiro - "shift" isn't a reserved word.

Comment: After 15 years of writing JavaScript, I just learned something new. Does this mean that JavaScript actually has a reference type? I can't think of any other way to have the (primitive) value of a variable change through a different reference. That is, data and type seem to be actual references to `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]`, I'd love to see a definitive reference about this and would love to be able to actually make use of references in JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler:

> Strict mode makes `arguments` less bizarrely magical.
>
> In normal code within a function whose first argument is `arg`,
>   setting `arg` also sets `arguments[0]`, and vice versa (**unless** no
>   arguments were provided or **`arguments[0]` is deleted**).
>
> `arguments` objects for strict mode functions store the original
>   arguments when the function was invoked. `arguments[i]` does not track
>   the value of the corresponding named argument, nor does a named
>   argument track the value in the corresponding `arguments[i]`.

You actually met the *"unless arguments[i] is deleted"* case ;)

Comment: Great link, this is also in the actual EcmaScript reference. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30459615/227299

Answer (score 3):

What you get is an arguments array with [data, type] and two more arguments not being used. Add a console.log before and after each shift and you'll see what happens;

```
var shift = [].shift;
console.log("args", arguments)
console.log(data, type);
// Outputs [1, 'test', 2, 3] => data = 1, type = 'test'

shift.call(arguments);
console.log("args", arguments)
console.log(data, type);
// Outputs ['test', 2, 3] => data = 'test', type = 2

shift.call(arguments);
console.log("args", arguments)
console.log(data, type);
// Outputs [2, 3] => data = 2, type = 3

shift.call(arguments);
console.log("args", arguments)
console.log(data, type);
// Outputs [3] => data = 3, type = 3 (type is keeping it's old value)

shift.call(arguments);
console.log("args", arguments)
console.log(data, type);
// Outputs [] => data = 3, type = 3 (both are keeping their old value)
```

Does this help?

Comment: it's unpredictable behaviour imho

Comment: Upvoted this, but there's an actual explanation... See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30459615/227299 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/30459864/227299

Answer (score 1):

In your case 'data' is a reference to the first position of the arguments array.
When you call your function the values are

```
arguments[0] => data => 1
arguments[1] => type => 'test'
arguments[2] => 2
arguments[3] => 3
```

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) says that array function shift it removes the first element. But also says

> shift is intentionally generic; this method can be called or applied to objects resembling arrays. Objects which do not contain a length property reflecting the last in a series of consecutive, zero-based numerical properties may not behave in any meaningful manner.

Internally the shift functions call the delete operator. After apply four times the arguments array is  [undefined, undefined]. Now the thing is that calling delete on a variable removes it but if there still a reference to the variable the value is not removed

```
delete arguments[0];
delete arguments[1];
console.log(arguments); => [2: 2, 3: 3] // Position 0 and 1 were removed. Lenght is still 4
console.log(data);  => 1
console.log(type);  => 'test'
```

So you see the variables are still being referenced regardless you deleted the value from arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-through of your code.

```
var a = function(data, type){
  var shift = [].shift;//data points to arguments[0], or 1
  shift.call(arguments); // arguments[0] is now 'test'
  shift.call(arguments); // arguments[0] is now 2
  shift.call(arguments); //arguments[0] is now 3
  shift.call(arguments); // data pointed @ 3, arguments[0] is undefined
  console.log(data);
}

a(1,'test', 2, 3);
```

JS seems to be doing some work in the background, where if the corresponding index of  `arguments` (which isn't an array) goes from truthy to falsy/undefined, the previous value gets retained.

Answer (score 0):

What you are observing is only true for non-strict JavaScript, so it shouldn't be relied on. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6, there's a section that explains the different behavior between strict and non-strict mode.

[Sp00m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30459864/227299) posted a [nice explanation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler)

From the EcmaScript specification

> NOTE 1:  For non-strict mode functions the array index (defined in 15.4) named data properties of an arguments object whose numeric name values are less than the number of formal parameters of the corresponding function object initially share their values with the corresponding argument bindings in the function’s execution context. **This means that changing the property changes the corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa**. This correspondence is broken if such a property is deleted and then redefined or if the property is changed into an accessor property. For strict mode functions, the values of the arguments object’s properties are simply a copy of the arguments passed to the function and there is no dynamic linkage between the property values and the formal parameter values.

```js
var a = function(data, type){
  var shift = [].shift;
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  console.log(data);
}

var b = function(data, type){
  'use strict';
  var shift = [].shift;
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  shift.call(arguments);
  console.log(data);
}

a(1,'test', 2, 3); // 3
b(1,'test', 2, 3); // 1
```